# c# DES Decryptor error while deserializing

Tags: c#, des, binaryformatter

I am getting some unexpected behavior from a DES Decryptor. I have a Windows Forms app that stores a user database class to a file and loads it later, which works fine.

Later I started working on a console app that also needs to open the same file and load the user database. I have copy/pasted the exact same code with the same des keys in my console app, but when I try to call LoadUserDatabase(), I get errors when Deserialize() is called:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to find assembly 'MyAssemblyName, Version=1.1.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'
```

Meanwhile the Forms app can freely Load and Save the database file. I'm really out of ideas as to why this may be happening.
Here is the code:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserDatabase
{
    public long dateSaved;
    public List<User> userData; //User is another serializable class
}
```

```
public static byte[] desKey = { x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x};
public static byte[] desIV = { x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x};

public void SaveUserDatabase()
{
    UserDatabase userDatabase = this.userDatabase;  //userDatabase is populated by the forms app
    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(databaseFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateEncryptor(desKey, desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, userDatabase);
    }
}

public void LoadUserDatabase()
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    using (var fs = new FileStream(databaseFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fs, des.CreateDecryptor(desKey, desIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        this.userDatabase = (UserDatabase)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception are you getting exactly? What's the stack trace? How is it that you're getting two different exceptions?

Comment: You have `UserDatabase` class created in both Forms and Console application? And you are storing the object in file from Forms application and trying to retrieve the same in console application?

Comment: Can you try to read directly from the crypto stream without deserializing, just to see if decryption is even successful? Something like `var fileSize = fs.Length;` then `var buffer = new byte[fileSize];` then `cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileSize);` then `foreach (var b in buffer) { Console.Write(b); }` and see that no exceptions are raised. It would also be useful to compare that output the unencrypted plaintext just before writing to file in the Windows Forms app. If they're the same, you have a serialization issue. If they're different, you have a crypto issue

Comment: This is the error I am getting. `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to find assembly 'MyAssemblyName, Version=1.1.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.' `

Comment: When using the BinaryFormatter you cannot mix and match assemblies.  If you serialize from WinFomrs app, it will ***only*** be able to be deserialized from the same assembly-class-version by design

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, after changing to Protobuf it is working.